# Form of potential operator of two interacting particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, potential

Considering two interacting  particles in 3d, the corresponding Hilbert space $H$ is the tensor product of the two  individual Hilbert spaces of the two  particles.

If the particle interaction is given by a potential $V(\mathbf r_1 -\mathbf r_2)$ ,what is the corresponding potential operator for it?

Answer (score 0):

The operator can be written this way
$$V(\mathbf{\hat{R}_1-\hat{R}_2})=\int d^3x~d^3y~V(x-y)|x,y\rangle\langle x,y|$$